# How to highlight the selected row of ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ag-grid

I am working on an example from ag-grid documentation on multiple Row Selection.Below is the code from the plunkr:

```
var columnDefs = [
{field: "athlete", width: 150},
{field: "age", width: 90},
{field: "country", width: 120},
{field: "year", width: 90},
{field: "date", width: 110},
{field: "sport", width: 110},
{field: "gold", width: 100},
{field: "silver", width: 100},
{field: "bronze", width: 100},
{field: "total", width: 100}
];

var gridOptions = {
columnDefs: columnDefs,
rowSelection: 'multiple',
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

// do http request to get our sample data - not using any framework to keep 
the example self contained.
// you will probably use a framework like JQuery, Angular or something else 
to do your HTTP calls.
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid- 
docs/master/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json');
httpRequest.send();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
        var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        gridOptions.api.setRowData(httpResult);
    }
};
});
```

But how to highlight multiple selected rows to understand it easily which rows are selected.

Comment: highlight selected rows of the grid - isn't this the default behaviour of ag-grid? what else do you want? could you share the plunk link?

Comment: Hi Paritosh as you said it is a default behaviour of ag-grid.I am trying with version 4.Its not highlighting the selected row.I tried with latest version 17 and i can see the highlighted row.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the gridOptions:

```
rowMultiSelectWithClick: true
```